# zend db fetchRow return trouble

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm coding up a page to show all data related to an item and I'm pulling up nulls when I try to access the data returned by this query.

```
DB::call()->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query = "SELECT name, release_date, points, availability, exclusivity, original_price,     sold_at, designer, model
    FROM items 
    WHERE item_id = '$id'";
$row = DB::call()->fetchRow($query);
$this->name = $row['name'];
//Same with other fields
```

DB is just a wrapper class for `Zend_DB` left by a previous programmer. I've ran the exact same query in PHPmyAdmin to make sure that it pulls up results. I'm assuming that my problem is how I'm trying to access the return data, since I'm not very familiar with Zend Framework. How should I be trying to access the data?

Comment: I've tried setting the fetch mode to object and then converting it to an array as follows: `$db = DB::call();
  $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
  $query = "SELECT name,etc.
      FROM items 
      WHERE item_id = '$id'";
  $results = $db->fetchRow($query);
  $results = $results->toArray();
  /*I'm not accessing data correctly here*/
  $this->name = $results['name'];` But then I just get an error that I can't call `toArray()` on a non-object.

Comment: try `var_dump($row);` and you shall know everything about it

Comment: It's coming up null both ways. When I run the query in PHPmyAdmin it pulls up the information every time. Any idea why the variable would be coming up null when the query itself is fine?

Comment: check the value of $query - if it's a valid query, you would have to start debugging the `fetchRow` and upper along the chain of the wrapper class

Comment: The item id being passed in from the controller was null because I apparently don't have my routes set up correctly.

Comment: Case solved ;) It would be great if you can close this question, as there is no value for others to gain from it. Thanks!

Comment: @DvirAzulay just post your solution as an answer and accept it. You never know if this could help someone.

Comment: @Iznogood: In the general thinking I totally agree with you, but if we have too much of "why this and that" and the answer is something unrelated to the question, this creates a lot of noise when searching for an actual answer to a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was invalid because the id being passed in was null. I simply have my routes set up incorrectly.